# Does every faithful action on a scheme act freely on a dense open subset?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group acting faithfully on a smooth quasi-projective $k$-scheme $X$ via automorphisms, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of any characteristic. Apparently, in characteristic $0$ it is then true that there is a dense, open and $G$-invariant subscheme $U \subseteq X$ on which $G$ acts freely, though I could not find a proof of this.

Now, I would like to know if this fact is also true in positive characteristic? Details or maybe a reference as to why this is true/false would be highly appreciated!

(I have read that it fails for finite group *schemes* over $k$, because then some infinitesimal phenomena appear, but maybe it is still true for finite groups.)

Comment: Have you tried looking at Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory?

Comment: @AHappyMathematician I have skimmed it, but I haven't found the result in question even for characteristic 0. Did I miss something?

Comment: I guess maybe not! I don't have the book with me. My reason for suspecting Mumford's book is that he more or less deals with $\operatorname{char}k=0$ throughout and so the result you're hoping for might just be a consequence of a result / or proof somewhere.